# How to wisely combine shingles and edgeNgram to provide flexible full text search?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, odata, analyzer

We have an OData-compliant API that delegates some of its full text search needs to an Elasticsearch cluster.
Since OData expressions can get quite complex, we decided to simply translate them into their equivalent Lucene query syntax and feed it into a `query_string` query.

We do support some text-related OData filter expressions, such as:

- `startswith(field,'bla')`
- `endswith(field,'bla')`
- `substringof('bla',field)`
- `name eq 'bla'`

The fields we're matching against can be `analyzed`, `not_analyzed` or both (i.e. via a multi-field).
The searched text can be a single token (e.g. `table`), only a part thereof (e.g. `tab`), or several tokens (e.g. `table 1.`, `table 10`, etc).
The search must be case-insensitive.

Here are some examples of the behavior we need to support:

- `startswith(name,'table 1')` must match "**Table 1**", "**table 1**00",  "**Table 1**.5", "**table 1**12 upper level"
- `endswith(name,'table 1')` must match "Room 1, **Table 1**", "Sub**table 1**", "**table 1**", "Jeff **table 1**"
- `substringof('table 1',name)` must match "Big **Table 1** back", "**table 1**", "**Table 1**", "Small **Table1**2"
- `name eq 'table 1'` must match "**Table 1**", "**TABLE 1**", "**table 1**"

So basically, we take the user input (i.e. what is passed into the 2nd parameter of `startswith`/`endswith`, resp. the 1st parameter of `substringof`, resp. the right-hand side value of the `eq`) and try to match it exactly, whether the tokens fully match or only partially.

Right now, we're getting away with a clumsy solution highlighted below which works pretty well, but is far from being ideal.

In our `query_string`, we match against a `not_analyzed` field using the [Regular Expression syntax](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html#regexp-syntax). Since the field is `not_analyzed` and the search must be case-insensitive, we do our own tokenizing while preparing the regular expression to feed into the query in order to come up with something like this, i.e. this is equivalent to the OData filter `endswith(name,'table 8')` (=> match all documents whose `name` ends with "table 8")

```
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "name.raw:/.*(T|t)(A|a)(B|b)(L|l)(E|e) 8/",
      "lowercase_expanded_terms": false,
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
```

So, even though, this solution works pretty well and the performance is not too bad (which came out as a surprise), we'd like to do it differently and leverage the full power of analyzers in order to shift all this burden at indexing time instead of searching time. However, since reindexing all our data will take weeks, we'd like to first investigate if there's a good combination of token filters and analyzers that would help us achieve the same search requirements enumerated above.

My thinking is that the ideal solution would contain some wise mix of shingles (i.e. several tokens together) and edge-nGram (i.e. to match at the start or end of a token). What I'm not sure of, though, is whether it is possible to make them work together in order to match several tokens, where one of the tokens might not be fully input by the user). For instance, if the indexed name field is "Big Table 123", I need `substringof('table 1',name)` to match it, so "table" is a fully matched token, while "1" is only a prefix of the next token.

Thanks in advance for sharing your braincells on this one.

**UPDATE 1: after testing Andrei's solution**

=> Exact match (`eq`) and `startswith` work perfectly.

A. `endswith` glitches

Searching for `substringof('table 112', name)` yields 107 docs. Searching for a more specific case such as `endswith(name, 'table 112')` yields 1525 docs, while it should yield less docs (suffix matches should be a subset of substring matches). Checking in more depth I've found some mismatches, such as "Social Club, Table 12" (doesn't contain "112") or "Order 312" (contains neither "table" nor "112"). I guess it's because they end with "12" and that's a valid gram for the token "112", hence the match.

B. `substringof` glitches

Searching for `substringof('table',name)` matches "Party table", "Alex on big table" but doesn't match "Table 1", "table 112", etc. Searching for `substringof('tabl',name)` doesn't match anything

**UPDATE 2**

It was sort of implied but I forgot to explicitely mention that the solution will have to work with the `query_string` query, mainly due to the fact that the OData expressions (however complex they might be) will keep getting translated into their Lucene equivalent. I'm aware that we're trading off the power of the Elasticsearch Query DSL with the Lucene's query syntax, which is a bit less powerful and less expressive, but that's something that we can't really change. We're pretty d**n close, though!

**UPDATE 3 (June 25th, 2019):**

ES 7.2 introduced a new data type called `search_as_you_type` that allows this kind of behavior natively. Read more at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/search-as-you-type.html

Comment: Wow, looks like Lucene regex is as primitive as it gets, really sparse in way of constructs, no case flags, etc.., Basically it just sucks. You can build your own expressions. Example `\d+` would be `[0-9]+`. You could even get a little fancy with unrolled-loop method.

Comment: I have more or less the exact same requirements, only I'm starting from scratch. Could you please elaborate on how you would setup and use `search_as_you_type`, if you tried going that route.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an interesting use case. Here's my take:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        },
        "my_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        },
        "my_reverse_edge_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter" : ["lowercase","reverse","substring","reverse"]
        },
        "lowercase_keyword": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"],
          "tokenizer": "keyword"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "25"
        },
        "my_edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "25"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 2,
          "max_gram": 25
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "test_type": {
      "properties": {
        "text": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer",
          "fields": {
            "starts_with": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_edge_ngram_analyzer"
            },
            "ends_with": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "my_reverse_edge_ngram_analyzer"
            },
            "exact_case_insensitive_match": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `my_ngram_analyzer` is used to split every text into small pieces, how large the pieces are depends on your use case. I chose, for testing purposes, 25 chars. `lowercase` is used since you said case-insensitive. Basically, this is the tokenizer used for `substringof('table 1',name)`. The query is simple:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text": {
        "value": "table 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `my_edge_ngram_analyzer` is used to split the text starting from the beginning and this is specifically used for the `startswith(name,'table 1')` use case. Again, the query is simple:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text.starts_with": {
        "value": "table 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- I found this the most tricky part - the one for `endswith(name,'table 1')`. For this I defined `my_reverse_edge_ngram_analyzer` which uses a `keyword` tokenizer together with `lowercase` and an `edgeNGram` filter preceded and followed by a [`reverse` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-reverse-tokenfilter.html). What this tokenizer basically does is to split the text in edgeNGrams but the edge is the end of the text, not the start (like with the regular `edgeNGram`).
  The query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text.ends_with": {
        "value": "table 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- for the `name eq 'table 1'` case, a simple `keyword` tokenizer together with a `lowercase` filter should do it
  The query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text.exact_case_insensitive_match": {
        "value": "table 1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Regarding **`query_string`**, this changes the solution a bit, because I was counting on `term` to not analyze the input text and to match it exactly with one of the terms in the index.

But this can be "simulated" with `query_string` [if the appropriate `analyzer` is specified for it](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html).

The solution would be a set of queries like the following (always use that analyzer, changing only the field name):

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "text.starts_with:(\"table 1\")",
      "analyzer": "lowercase_keyword"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Andrei, thanks a lot for your suggestion, much appreciated! I've updated my question as we've added support for `eq` in the meantime (for a case-insensitive exact match). How would you approach that case?

Comment: For the `eq` part it should be a straight forward `keyword` tokenizer + `lowercase` filter. Updated my answer.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your prompt answer! I'm going to shake it all out on real data and come back here asap, but at first glance I'm pretty confident it'll work out well. Stay tuned...

Comment: It works 99% great, very promising solution! Exact match and `startswith` work perfectly, though I've found some glitches with `substringof` and `endswith`. I'm updating my question above with some results.

Comment: Hm, I have one explanation for one mismatch, but I have the feeling you are not testing this with a `term`, but with a `match` or something else. The different thing in your updated tests is that you are searching text with upper case letters :-), like `Table 112`. For this to match the terms in the index, the `index` and `search` analyzers need to be separated. For `search` I'm thinking `keyword` and `lowercase` and not using `term` query, but a `match`.

Comment: My bad, I did search for lowercase, but included a capital case in my update above by mistake.

Comment: Hm, then how are you testing? What is the query used? I tested with `{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "text.ends_with": {
        "value": "table 112"
      }
    }
  }
}` and it only returns the "table 112" document.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80251/discussion-between-val-and-andrei-stefan).

Comment: That's it, we have a winner. Thanks Andrei!

Comment: Andrei, dropping by to let you know that your solution is working perfectly (with an expected 4x storage increase) and we're going to deploy this into production next week. "Just" need to reindex 2TB of data first :-) Thanks again.

Comment: :-) glad to hear that. And more glad that you took the time to share this.

Comment: First attempt failed, the cluster wasn't properly sized and everything fell apart domino-style :-) Stay tuned for second attempt...

Comment: :-) ...ok, what do you mean by properly sized? What boxes do you have?

Comment: Simply not enough nodes and not enough RAM on each to handle the additional data, but we're working on making this right and I'll share the results once it works.