# Data explorer API on ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, rest, elasticsearch, restful-architecture

We store searchable data in `ElasticSearch` and We show this to our dashboard (written in `C#`) through `NEST` but now we are planning to make `Data explorer API` so our customers can fetch data through API to their system. My Question is what is best way to provide a API which can accept a query and return data to user. Is there any approach which allow to expose `ElasticSearch` data securely, I can't accept direct Elastic Query from customer as API parameter.

I am not sure how to do this but I have one thing in my mind I'll create a Query System, I'll define its specs and validation, And finally I'll create query translator to translate to ElasticSearch.

Comment: Why not simply using [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index.html) which does exactly that?

Comment: Need API not UI for data explorer, UI we already have, through API our customer can fetch data to their system.

Comment: No sure about best one. but you can take a look around OData where you can filter data over search bar. its good for basic custom search operation. but could give you some idea where you can pull you system.

Comment: Also take look in expression tree builders.

Comment: You might find some inspiration in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc) I asked in the past. It involves ES and OData.