# How to match parts of a word in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I match parts of a word to the parent word ?. For example: I need to match "eese" or "heese" to the word "cheese".

Answer (score 7):

The best way to achieve this is using an [`edgeNGram` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenfilter.html) combined with two [`reverse` token filters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-reverse-tokenfilter.html). So, first you need to define a custom analyzer called `reverse_analyzer` in your index settings like below. Then you can see that I've declared a string field called `your_field` with a sub-field called `suffix` which has our custom analyzer defined.

```
PUT your_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "reverse_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "keyword",
          "filter" : ["lowercase", "reverse", "substring", "reverse"]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "substring": {
          "type": "edgeNGram",
          "min_gram": 1,
          "max_gram": 10
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "your_field": {
          "type": "string",
          "fields": {
            "suffix": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "reverse_analyzer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index a test document with "cheese" inside, like this:

```
PUT your_index/your_type/1
{"your_field": "cheese"}
```

When this document is indexed, the `your_field.suffix` field will contain the following tokens:

- `e`
- `se`
- `ese`
- `eese`
- `heese`
- `cheese`

Under the hood what is happening when indexing `cheese` is the following:

1. The `keyword` tokenizer will tokenize a single token, => `cheese`
2. The `lowercase` token filter will put the token in lowercase => `cheese`
3. The `reverse` token filter will reverse the token => `eseehc`
4. The `substring` token filter will produce different tokens of length 1 to 10 => `e`, `es`, `ese`, `esee`, `eseeh`, `eseehc`
5. Finally, the second `reverse` token filter will reverse again all tokens => `e`, `se`, `ese`, `eese`, `heese`, `cheese`
6. Those are all the tokens that will be indexed

So we can finally search for `eese` (or any suffix of `cheese`) in that sub-field and find our match

```
POST your_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "your_field.suffix": "eese"
      }
   }
}
```

=> Yields the document we've just indexed above.

Comment: Hi is there a way to make it work for both sufffix and prefix. i.e.) indexed word "Cheese" and i want to search it with "2chee" or "Cheese2"

Comment: @The6thSense yes see my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666371/4604579) and look for how to solve the `substringof` problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it two ways:

1. If you need it happen only for some search then search box only you can pass

   *eese*   or *heese*

Just give * in beginning and end of your search word. If you need it for every search

```
 string "*#{params[:query]}*"
```

this will match with your parent word and give the result

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this

1. The analyzer approach - Here you [Ngram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) to break sub tokens of all the words. Hence for the word "cheese" -> [ "chee" , "hees" , "eese" , "cheese" ] and all ind of substrings would be generated. With this index size will go high , but the search speed would be optimized
2. The [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) approach - In this approach , a scan happens on the reverse index. This does not occupy additional index size , but it will take more time on the search.