# How to get case-insensitive result with exact match in elastic search jhipster project

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-boot

On working with Jhipster project with spring boot- 1.4.0-RELEASE and elastic search-2.3.5.
When I index data with analyzed then on search with different query builders, it result differently and incorrectly. But on changing the indexing to **not_analyzed** then most of the filter works fine except the search is case-sensitive.

To not_analyzed data we have added this annotation on entity class string fields :

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store = true)
```

The operators on which I have to perform search are :

- Is
- IsNot
- IsOneOf
- IsNotOneOf
- Contains
- DoesNotContains
- StartsWith
- EndsWith

So with not_analyzed index, it return correct result except case-sensitivity of searched string.

On researching, we found that we can use keyword analyzer with tokenizer lower case to perform search, I have searched but all return solution with lucene spring or elastic search queries. I want solution using spring boot elastic search. How can we apply this in annotation or while sending search request.

We want to make the search case-insensitive but it should give correct result for all operators. Is there any way?

Comment: I once had a very similar need, feel free to check my question and the related answer, I think it might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Comment: @Val Thanks your link helped me to resolve the issue!

Comment: Feel free to upvote the question ;-)