# Elastic search exact match and partial matching on Float Field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot

I am working on a JHipster project with spring boot- 1.4.0-RELEASE and elastic search-2.3.5.

The operators on which I have to perform search are :

```
Is
IsNot
IsOneOf
IsNotOneOf
Contains
DoesNotContain
StartsWith
EndsWith
```

Right now, I have a float field in my entity. It has the following annotation:-

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Float, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store = true)
```

The following operators do not work on the float field:-

```
Contains
DoesNotContain
StartsWith
EndsWith
```

I tried changing the index type to string by changing the annotation to:-

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store = true)
```

But it stopped giving correct results for operators:-

```
Is
IsNot
IsOneOf
IsNotOneOf
EndsWith
```

**For eg:-** I have values 1, 6, 77, 17 and 285.7

I try to search **ends with 7** then it gives **only 285.7** as the result instead of 77, 17 and 285.7

Also If I search **is 6** then I **get 0 results** but If I search **is 6.0** then I get 1 result. I need to get the 1 hit even if I search with query **is 6**

Comment: I once had a very similar need, feel free to check my question and the related answer, I think it might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Comment: @Val Thanks for the link. I already tried the suggestion given in this link for case insensitive search and it works perfectly. But it doesn't work on a Float field even if it is stored as string in indexes.