# Using reverse token with a custom normalizer

Tags: elasticsearch

Apparently when I try to run the following mapping

```
 "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ]
        },
        "my_reverse_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "char_filter": [],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "reverse"
          ]
        }
      }
```

I get:

```
Custom normalizer [my_reverse_normalizer] may not use filter [reverse]
```

What workaround can I apply? I need my keyword normalized and be able to use suffix queries as well that's why I am planning to tokenize using reverse.

Comment: It seems to be the same issue as you pointed out [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/27310)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that doesn't work with normalizers you can always create a normal custom analyzer with a `keyword` tokenizer and the `reverse` token filter

```
  "normalizer": {
    "my_normalizer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "char_filter": [],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    }
  },
  "analyzer": {
    "my_reverse_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "char_filter": [],
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "reverse"
      ]
    }
  }
```

Note, however, that if you need to do suffix search, you need two `reverse` filters. See this my other [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc) on this topic

Comment: Clever solution