# Match query contains forward slash in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Elasticsearch version: 6.3.2

I encountered a problem while searching for attribute values which contain forward slash (/).
The index is like:

```
{
  "day": 1/5/2018
},
{
  "day": 2/3/2017
},
{
  "day": 5/7/2018
}
...
```

now I want to search for "1/5" and get the records which contain "1/5".

The query is:

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "day": "1/5*"
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query":  "*1/5*",
            "field": day
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

But I got the exception:

```
"Cannot parse '*1/5*': Lexical error at line 1, column 6.  Encountered: <EOF> after : \"/5*\"",
```

I tried to replace 1/5 to 1\\/5 and the error disappeared and I can get some results but they are not I want.

The results just contains "1" or "5" or neither, how can I get the results which contain "1/5"?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Since this is a date field, it would be much easier if you also indexed the day, month and year in three separate fields that you can query in a much more optimal way using ranges

Comment: @Val Actually this is a text field I just use the this for an example... I need to perform full-text query on the filed. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Ok, since you need to search for prefixes and infixes, I suggest you look at the following thread which provides both solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Answer (score 0):

that single \ is for JSON escaping. To have it make its way through to the query string, you need to double escape it: **blabla\/bla\/bla\/bla**
or
one slash
 **blabla/bla/bla/bla**