# Elastic Search: Query string and number not always returning wanted result

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We have an elastic search 5.5 setup. We use nest to perform our queries through C#.

When executing the following query:

> ```
> {
>   "query": {
>     "bool": {
>       "must": [
>         {
>           "query_string": {
>             "query": "00917751"
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

We get the desired result: one result with that the number as identifier.

When executing the query:

> ```
> {
>   "query": {
>     "bool": {
>       "must": [
>         {
>           "query_string": {
>             "query": "917751"
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

We get no results.

The value we are searching for is in the field searchIndentifier, and has the value "1-00917751".

We have a custom analyzer called "final"

> .Custom("final", cu => cu
>                                   .Tokenizer("keyword").Filters(new List() { "lowercase" }))

The field searchIndentifier has no custom analyzer set on it. I tried adding the whitespace tokenizer in it but that made no difference.

Another field called "searchObjectNo" does work, when I try to search for the value "S328-25" with the query "S328". These fields are exactly the same.

Any ideas here?

Another related question:
When executing the query

> ```
> {
>   "query": {
>     "bool": {
>       "must": [
>         {
>           "query_string": {
>             "query": "1-00917751"
>           }
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

we get a lot of results. I would like this to return only 1 result. How would we accomplish this?

Thank you
Schoof

Settings and mapping: https://jsonblob.com/9dbf33f6-cd3e-11e8-8f17-c9de91b6f9d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `searchIndentifier` field is mapped as a `text` datatype, which will undergo analysis and use the Standard Analyzer by default. Using the Analyze API, you can see what terms will be stored in the inverted index for `1-00917751`

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var analyzeResponse = client.Analyze(a => a
    .Text("1-00917751")
);
```

which returns

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "1",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 1,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "00917751",
      "start_offset" : 2,
      "end_offset" : 10,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 1
    }
  ]
}
```

You'll get a match for the `query_string` query with a query input of `00917751` as this matches one of the terms stored in the inverted index as a result of analysis at index time for the input `1-00917751`.

You won't get a match for `917751` as there is not a term in the inverted index that will match. You could define an analysis chain that removes leading zeroes from numbers as well as preserving the original token e.g.

```
private static void Main()
{
    var defaultIndex = "foobarbaz";
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    client.CreateIndex(defaultIndex, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .Analysis(a => a
                .Analyzers(an => an
                    .Custom("trim_leading_zero", ca => ca
                        .Tokenizer("standard")
                        .Filters(
                            "standard", 
                            "lowercase", 
                            "trim_leading_zero",
                            "trim_zero_length")
                    )
                )
                .TokenFilters(tf => tf
                    .PatternReplace("trim_leading_zero", pr => pr
                        .Pattern("^0+(.*)")
                        .Replacement("$1")
                    )
                    .Length("trim_zero_length", t => t
                        .Min(1)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(n => n.SearchIndentifier)
                        .Analyzer("trim_leading_zero")
                        .Fields(f => f
                            .Keyword(k => k
                                .Name("keyword")
                                .IgnoreAbove(256)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    client.Index(new MyDocument { SearchIndentifier = "1-00917751" }, i => i
        .Refresh(Refresh.WaitFor)
    );

    client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
        .Query(q => q
            .QueryString(qs => qs
                .Query("917751")
            )
        )
    );
}

public class MyDocument 
{
    public string SearchIndentifier { get; set; }
}
```

The `pattern_replacement` token filter will trim leading zeroes from tokens.

the search query returns the indexed document

```
{
  "took" : 69,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 0.33310556,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "foobarbaz",
        "_type" : "mydocument",
        "_id" : "MVF4bmYBJZHQAT-BUx1K",
        "_score" : 0.33310556,
        "_source" : {
          "searchIndentifier" : "1-00917751"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! I'll be trying this out shortly. What would the result be if you search for 1-00917751? And 00917751?

Comment: You can use the Analyze API against the field to see what the resulting terms from analysis would be: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/testing-analyzers.html#_testing_an_analyzer_on_a_field

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Would you perhaps have an answer to my other question? (about searching for "1-00917751") and returning a lot of results.

Comment: Just set `"size"` to `1` on the request, which will return only the top result