# how to make contains/ like query with elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to achieve below tsql query with eleasticsearch

```
declare @searchstring nvarchar (max) 

set @searchstring = 'tn-241'

set @searchstring = replace(replace('%'+@searchstring+'%', '-', ''), ' ', '')

    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].[Product] 
    where 
        replace(replace(shortdescription, '-', ''), ' ', '') like @searchstring or
        replace(replace(name, '-', ''), ' ', '') like @searchstring or
        replace(replace(number, '-', ''), ' ', '') like  @searchstring
```

for that i have created analyzer using keyword tokenizer and delimeter filter with catenate_all as below

```
"search_delimiter": {
"split_on_numerics": "false",
"generate_word_parts": "false",
"preserve_original": "false",
"generate_number_parts": "false",
"catenate_all": "true",
"split_on_case_change": "false",
"type": "word_delimiter",
"stem_english_possessive": "false"
}
       "analyzer": {
    "searchanalyzer": {
    "filter": [
    "lowercase"
    ,
    "search_delimiter"
    ],
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "keyword"


},
"Name": {
"analyzer": "searchanalyzer",
"type": "string",
"fields": {
"raw": {
"analyzer": "searchanalyzer",
"type": "string"
}
}
},
"Number": {
"analyzer": "searchanalyzer",
"type": "string",
"fields": {
"raw": {
"analyzer": "searchanalyzer",
"type": "string"
}
}
}
"ShortDescription": {
"analyzer": "searchanalyzer",
"type": "string",
"fields": {
"raw": {
"analyzer": "searchanalyzer",
"type": "string"
}
}
},
```

Which results as

```
curl -XGET "Index/_analyze?analyzer=searchanalyzer&pretty=true" -d "Original Brother TN-241C Toner Cyan"
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "originalbrothertn241ctonercyan",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 35,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 0
  } ]
}
}
```

So I need to basically apply same analyzer and use query_string or wild card search which supposed to do instring search

So if i search like below

```
"query": {
    "query_string" : {
        "fields" : ["Name", "Number", "ShortDescription"],
        "query" : "*TonerCyan*"           
    }
}
```

it works fine but if I search

```
  "query": {
        "query_string" : {
            "fields" : ["Name", "Number", "ShortDescription"],
            "query" : "*Toner Cyan*"           
        }
    }
```

it wont return any results, it means that searchanalyzer is not applied before it executes query_string because i expect it should search for TonerCyan in the 2nd query also instead Toner and Cyan separately? First question is why this doesnt work? 2nd is what is the best way to achieve tsql query above? It should search multiple fields

Comment: this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Comment: @Val thanks for your answer but I have already experience with nedgegram analyzer, although it is one of the best analyzer, it doesnt suit in our case, it basically returns much more results than it is expected. it fails in many cases when there are -, /,( etc signs. I surely combined it with standard, keyword and whitespace analyzers but couldnt achieve expected results. I believe that above analyzer is perfect for our case, it does what supposed to do for indexing but I cant understand why it doesnt work for search analyzer

Comment: @Val I have to admit, i am not good at query_string, so i dont know the principal of it but when I use with multi match or match queries, search analyzer works as expected but multi match query isnot providing contains query like query_string does. or maybe can be achieved with wildcard but i just couldnt figure this out

Comment: @Val your examples are like ours but I need more like table1, table-1, table/1,table 1 should have exact same results. thats why i just created searchanalyzer above which removes all special chars and spaces and makes it "table1" only for search tiime, it should do also indexed values and *table1* query_string should match. but obviously searcanalyzer isnt applied for search keyword at the time of search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you can try to put the search string inside double quotes like this and that should work:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [
        "Name",
        "Number",
        "ShortDescription"
      ],
      "query": "*\"Toner Cyan\"*"
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you should know that searching for prefix wildcards can have catastrophic performance implications depending on the amount of data you have. I'm still convinced that you should index ngrams for that very reason.

Comment: with double quotes really works but what does it mean? what do double quotes do here?

Comment: the double quotes prevent the input from being tokenized into two tokens

Comment: this one is surely working. thats why i gave thumbs up but i am still evaluating performance and better option. otherwise i will accept your response. thanks again

Comment: I've hinted at what a better option would be in my earlier comments and at the end of my answer: using ngrams ;-)