# How to search by prefix in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

For this query:

```
  "filter": [
    {
      "prefix": {
        "issuer": "teva"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I get `"issuer": "TEVA PHARMACEUTICAL INDUSTRIES LTD"`

But if i try to search "teva p" i get nothing.
So, how can i simply do prefix query ?

Comment: By default your column is analyzed and stored as words, not as a whole, so you have `["TEVA", "PHARMACEUTICAL", "INDUSTRIES", "LTD"]` (figuratively). You can try using a [wildcard query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) which is using a non-analyzed value (also case sensitive IIRC).

Comment: Tokenizer("standard")?

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Answer (score 0):

You can use [phrase prefix match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html) query.

```
POST phrase_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "issuer": "teva p"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me only this is working:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "TEVA P"
    }
  }
}
```

Maybe it is depends on `Tokenizer`