# Applying increasingly slow query filters depending on the number of matches

Tags: elasticsearch, query-optimization

Is there a way of building a ES query so that it doesn't apply slower parts like wildcard searches or including more fields... If the number of results with the previous conditions already reaches the specified query size?

I assume putting aside totalHits value.

I have tried playing with the boosting setting but ES expectedly applies all the combinations.

```
{
"size" : 5,
"query": {
"bool": {
"should" : [
    { "term" : { "search.autocomplete" : { "value" : "120", "boost" : 20 } }},
    { "term" : { "search.autocomplete_inverse" : { "value" : "120", "boost" : 15 } }},
    { "match" : { "search.keyword" : { "query" : "120", "boost" : 10 } }},
    { "wildcard" : { "brand.search" : { "value" : "*120*", "boost": 5}}},
    { "wildcard" : { "category.search" : { "value" : "*120*", "boost": 0}}}
]
}
}
}
```

A way so that if the first condition matches with 5 or more docs ES doesn't spend more time trying to find more matches.

A different approach would be to execute multiple queries in my application until I reach the desired amount of results, but it doesn't feel right...

Comment: A yet another approach would be to refrain from using wildcard queries with prefix wildcards `*120*`, that's a performance killer. You can also try to leverage [`minimum_should_match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-minimum-should-match.html) but getting rid of the wildcard queries is definitely a great gain

Comment: Hi Val, the way i understand minimum_should_match, if I set it to 1 it is going skip some work on the already matching elements, but still its going to apply all the filters  in the rest of the index. About your initial idea... is there another way to perform a "contains-like"(in the middle of a word) filter in ES?

Comment: Regarding "contains like", I once had the same problem. See this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Comment: If I understand it well, with this solution i wouldn't get a match for "table" inside "BigTable1". I would only get matches at the beginning/ending of the words with the edgengram/reversed-edgengram + matches at the beginning of the split tokens by the ngram tokenizer.

Comment: No you can get matches anywhere in the string because the string is analyzed by `my_ngram_tokenizer` which will tokenize the full string into substrings of varying length, so you'd match `table` inside `BigTable1` as well