# LIKE in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a project on Spring data elasticSearch. 
Model:

```
@Document(indexName = "address", createIndex = true)
public class Address {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text )
    private String fullAddress;

    private String regionCode;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Nested, store = true)
    private List<Entry> parts;

    public Address(String fullAddress) {
        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
    }

    public Address(String fullAddress, List<Entry> entryList) {
        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
        this.parts = entryList;
    }

    public Address(String fullAddress, List<Entry> entryList, String regionCode) {
        this.fullAddress = fullAddress;
        this.parts = entryList;
        this.regionCode = regionCode;
    }
}
```

Repository (fullAddress == "*Russia Moscow*"; without @Query, the method does not work with a key containing a space)

```
@Repository
public interface AddressElasticRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Address, String> {
    @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"field\" : {\"fullAddress\" : {\"query\" : \"?\",\"analyze_wildcard\" : true}}}}}")
    List<Address> findByFullAddressLike(String fullAddress);
}
```

My index in Elastic:

```
{
  "address": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "fullAddress": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "parts": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "aoGuid": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "aoLevel": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "aoid": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "code": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "offName": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "parentGuid": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "postalCode": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            },
            "shortName": {
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "type": "keyword",
                  "ignore_above": 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "regionCode": {
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "1s",
        "number_of_shards": "1",
        "provided_name": "address",
        "creation_date": "1582120325272",
        "store": {
          "type": "fs"
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "CG3m-SDdT9CqpXXJ2knl4g",
        "version": {
          "created": "7040099"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I make a call to the findByFullAddressLike method, I get an error:

> **org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchStatusException: Elasticsearch
>   exception [type=parsing_exception, reason=no [query] registered for
>   [field]]**    at
>   org.elasticsearch.rest.BytesRestResponse.errorFromXContent(BytesRestResponse.java:177)
>   ~[elasticsearch-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]  at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1727)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.parseResponseException(RestHighLevelClient.java:1704)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1467)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1424)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1394)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.search(RestHighLevelClient.java:930)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]   at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.search(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:240)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.query.ElasticsearchStringQuery.execute(ElasticsearchStringQuery.java:95)
>   ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.0.0.BUILD-20200217.043541-321.jar:4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
>     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
>   ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.findByFullAddressLike(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
>   ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
>   ~[spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy125.findByFullAddressLike(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
>     at
>   ru.evolenta.server.service.impl.ElasticQueryAddressServiceImpl.search(ElasticQueryAddressServiceImpl.java:98)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   ru.evolenta.server.controller.SearchController.search(SearchController.java:53)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_201]   at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:870)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:158)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:126)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:111)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:84)
>   ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   ru.evolenta.server.filters.SimpleCORSFilter.doFilter(SimpleCORSFilter.java:51)
>   ~[classes/:na]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
>   ~[spring-security-web-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_201]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_201]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_201]  **Suppressed:
>   org.elasticsearch.client.ResponseException: method [POST], host
>   [http://localhost:9200], URI
>   [/address/_search?typed_keys=true&ignore_unavailable=false&expand_wildcards=open&allow_no_indices=true&ignore_throttled=true&search_type=dfs_query_then_fetch&batched_reduce_size=512&ccs_minimize_roundtrips=true],
>   status line [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request]
>   {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no
>   [query] registered for
>   [field]","line":1,"col":32}],"type":"parsing_exception","reason":"no
>   [query] registered for [field]","line":1,"col":32},"status":400}**        at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.convertResponse(RestClient.java:253)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]      at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:231)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]      at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:205)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]      at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
>   ~[elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client-7.4.0.jar:7.4.0]       ... 103
>   common frames omitted

What should I do to make the error go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error states

> no [query] registered for [field]

You're query is not correct (i.e. `field` is not a valid query), it should be

```
@Query("{\"bool\":{\"must\":{\"query_string\":{\"query\":\"?\",\"default_field\":\"fullAddress\",\"analyze_wildcard\":true}}}}")
```

Comment: Thank you, the error has disappeared, but for some reason it is looking for the wrong data

Comment: That's another issue which is now related to your query and the way you're trying to do a LIKE

Comment: If translated into SQL, then my query would look like this: select * from address where fullAddress like "%Russia Moscow%"

Comment: Yes, I got that, but you cannot translate to that to query_string + prefix/suffix wildcards. This thread should help you achieve what you want, though: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666371/4604579

Comment: Looks like I should have read more up-to-date documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.0.x/reference/html/#elasticsearch.query-methods