# Wildcard search in Elasticsearch with a string field having only one word

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, wildcard

I have a use case where a string type field in my index which has single word(vehicle number) as its values and it needs to be searched in the following manner:  `*abc*`

What is the best way to achieve it and what will be the performance impact of the same?

Currently I am using the following query: `_search?q=vehicleNumber:*119*` which seems to me highly unoptimised.

Comment: This thread should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a leading wildcard can get pretty expensive... If you're primarily searching number "substrings" with that wildcard and its format is standardized (think car plate numbers in the form of `XX-12345-AB`), you could extract just those numbers into an additional field and then do range queries on it. That's certainly going to be faster than wildcarding on strings.

---

Another option would be to use [regex queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) which would be helpful if you for instance know the position of where you wanna search. It turns out IMEIs do have a certain structure -- `AA-BBBBBB-CCCCCC-EE` -- from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity)

[image: Slots]

So if you're looking for a serial number match, you'd skip to index 8:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "regexp": {
      "vehicleNumber": {
        "value": ".{8,}119.*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

Wrapping up, `regexp` and `wildcard` use the [same automaton in the background](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/prefix-vs-wildcard-vs-regexp-in-terms-of-performance-and-usability/98460/2) so there are no speed performance improvements choosing between the two when doing `leading *` queries. But when you do know the position, I suspect `regexp` might be more optimized for this.

Comment: This can help in case of vehicle number but what if i have to store say IMEI number of mobile and have to do a substring search on that...how can we solve that?

Comment: If you don't intend to change anything in your mapping, I reckon your approach is as optimized as it gets.

Comment: Can I use any kind of tokenizer or analyzer..something like ngram?

Comment: I don't think an ngram would help here. You'd use one when you're for instance wanting to support fuzzy queries and take care of misspellings. But since you're interested in substring matches, I'd say the wildcard query. You may also consider using regex queries -- I'll update my answer with this info.