# Elasticsearch, search for word starting with

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the below list of words

1. Advertising and communications specialist
2. Computer Developer
3. Community Manager
4. Computer Programmer

My query is as below:-

```
{
"query": {
    "wildcard": {
       "description": {
          "value": "Com*"
       }
    }
}
}
```

The results is including "Advertising and communications specialist". Basically i want to return only results starting with "Com".

Are there any other query i can run to achieve this?

My mapping is as follows:-

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "idForeign": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        },
        "idjobList": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This thread might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666371/4604579

Answer (score 2):

You can use prefix query in elastic search.

```
{
  "query": {
    "prefix": {
       "description.keyword": {
          "value": "Com"
       }
    }
 }
}
```

[Refer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html)

As your data sample contains Com, the above query will work. Below notes for your information.

Note, prefix query is a term query which means query text is not analyzed. Means it is case sensitive too.

If you need to make case insensitive search, you may need to change mapping of your data.

**Update:**

There are couple of ways to do that.

1. Using ngram on description field - set min and max gram wisely - so it will generate tokens between min to max grams. Then `com` will work on that.
2. You can use normalizer.

`lowercase_normalizer` would be as below

```
{
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "lowercase_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase"]
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Mapping:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "text",
      "normalizer": "lowercase_normalizer"
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can use the same prefix query - case insensitive manner. But note here type of name is keyword. If you need to keep text, you should use the first `ngram` option.

Comment: Just tried that, i still get "Advertising and communications specialist" and also "Commissioned Security Officer", the 2nd is ok, but the 1st is not

Comment: Try keyword as I updated the answer. If tats also not working pls post ur mapping for description @user2327579

Comment: i tried the above, it does work but its case sensitive, is there any way i can achive the same but case insensitve? I've added the mappings as requested.

Comment: Are you ok to change the mapping to achieve that?

Comment: Yes if need be, i can change it