# How to match elastic search query partial match multiple query?

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

My DSL query is below

```
GET index_name/_search
{
"query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "*avi*",
      "fields" : [
        "data.name"
      ]
    }}}
```

I need to add `"query" : "*ojh*"` also.

Below query not working

```
GET index_name/_search
{
"query" : {
    "query_string" : {
      "query" : "*avi*",
      "query" : "*ojh*",
      "fields" : [
        "data.name"
      ]
    }}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leverage the `bool/should` query and add two `query_string` queries:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*avi*",
            "fields": [
              "data.name"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*ojh*",
            "fields": [
              "data.name"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Just note, though, that doing infix searches like this can kill the performance of your cluster. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30666371/4604579) on how to properly do "substring" searches.

Comment: If i need to add 3 then condition then again i need to add one condition?         `{
          "query_string": {
            "query": "*mak*",
            "fields": [
              "data.name"
            ]
          }`