# IS DSL query on bool with one value and one query string is semantically same

Tags: elasticsearch, dsl

First DSL query

`{"query" : {"query_string" : {"query" : "*avi*", "fields" : ["data"]}}}`

Second DSL query with bool values

`{"query": {"bool": {"should": [{"query_string": {"query": "*avi*", "fields": ["data"]}}]}}}`

Both output remain same

Comment: Not sure what you're asking...

Comment: @Val Both my query give same output . Is the query is similar?

Comment: Yes, it's semantically exactly the same query

Comment: I introduced `bool/should` in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62988302/4604579) because you wanted to have two sub-queries... I'm not sure what the issue is with the query above as bool with one condition yields the same output as the condition itself without the bool query

Comment: @Val am trying to create query in python in dynamically . I am new to DSL query. just want to know whether it is semantically correct or not. you said it is same. I trust you . THank you so much for writing the answer. try to upwote your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, both queries are semantically the same.

You can use the former if you have only one constraint and the latter if you need to add more constraints like in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62988302/4604579).