# I'm having a problem with elasticsearch, how do I query for these conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having a problem with elasticsearch, how do I query for these conditions

```
beginsWith
endsWith
contains
```

Comment: Also worth having a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What query you tried?

Comment: @Kaveh answer helped me to solve the problem. Thanks all

Answer (score 2):

You can use Wildcard Query to perform such queries, A wildcard operator is a placeholder that matches one or more characters. For example, the * wildcard operator matches zero or more characters. You can combine wildcard operators with other characters to create a wildcard pattern.

in your case you can use wildCard query like below for example to check if string start contain or endwith 'od':

```
beginsWith : od*
endsWith: *od
contains: *od*
```

Rest API call example for all terms contains "od":

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "text": {
        "value": "*od*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

for more information you can check ES official documentation here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: Thank you very much. this is what i am looking for

Comment: Happy to help you, pleasee upvote and accept the answer.