# Convert OData to JSON for Elasticsearch

Tags: json, rest, parsing, elasticsearch, odata

I've an OData query that has multiple parameters. How do I convert this to a valid JSON so that I can process it further to query Elasticsearch?

Eg: 
OData : `$filter=CodeName eq 'beta' or loaded eq true and deprecated eq false or flagged eq true`

To a valid JSON?

I am parsing an incoming OData query and I've to query Elasticsearch with the required format.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but could you suggest me some better ways to do it?