# Elasticsearch - how to provide value to an inner field in ingest pipeline

Tags: elasticsearch

I have created an index whose mapping looks like this:

```json
{
  "corona_data_search_ac_poc" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "Country" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "Date" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "IsImplicitIntent" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "PopularityScore" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "Query" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "query_suggest" : {
              "type" : "completion",
              "analyzer" : "simple",
              "preserve_separators" : true,
              "preserve_position_increments" : true,
              "max_input_length" : 50
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample document looks like this:

```json
{"Date": "01-01-2020", "Query": "coronavirus is deadly", "IsImplicitIntent": true, "Country": "United States", "PopularityScore": 1}
```

I am using `Query.query_suggest` for autocompletion. For this purpose, I generate a list of suffixes of the `Query` field using a script in the ingest pipeline.
So for example, if `"Query": "coronavirus is deadly"`, then
`"Query.query_suggest"` should look like this:

```json
"query_suggest" : {
   "input" : [
      "coronavirus is deadly",
      "is deadly",
      "deadly"
    ]
}
```

Now, I am able to generate the suffix list using the below script:

```json
{
  "script": {
     "source": """
        def tokens = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(/\s+/.split(ctx.Query)));
        def nbTokens = tokens.size();
        def input = [];
        for (def i = nbTokens; i > 0; i--) {
           input.add(tokens.join(" "));
           tokens.remove(0);
        }
    
        # how to assign the list to the inner field?
        ctx.Query.query_suggest = [
          'input': input
        ]
        """
  }
}
```

I am not sure how should I assign the list to the inner field (see the comment in above script) so that ES can build autocomplete graph on top of that data?

NOTE: If I define `query_suggest` at the same level as `Query` in the mappings and then assigning values like `ctx.query_suggest` in the script, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mapping of your `Query` field is not correct. You won't be able to index what you expect because the query field is of type `text` and won't accept the same input as required by the suggest field, they have to be separate fields.

You need to have two separate fields at the top level:

```json
    "Query" : {
      "type" : "text"
    },
    "Query_Suggest": {
      "type" : "completion",
      "analyzer" : "simple",
      "preserve_separators" : true,
      "preserve_position_increments" : true,
      "max_input_length" : 50
    }
```

Then indexing this:

```
PUT test/_doc/1?pipeline=my-pipeline
{
  "Query": "coronavirus is deadly"
}
```

Will yields this:

```json
{
  "Query" : "coronavirus is deadly",
  "Query_Suggest" : {
    "input" : [
      "coronavirus is deadly",
      "is deadly",
      "deadly"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: as I already mentioned that if I create both the fields at the same level, then it works. I was looking for a way when I nest the "query_suggest" under the "query" field.
Is it possible to achieve the same thing when "query_suggest" is an inner field of "query". Do you know any other means of achieving the same result using inner fields.

Comment: No, it's not possible, as the `Query` field expects a string and the `completion` field expect a different input. It could be possible if you'd index the same data (i.e. the string `coronavirus is deadly`) in both fields, but since you have a different need for the completion field, it won't work, you need two different fields

Comment: Going with the solution that creates both the fields at the same level.

Comment: One more doubt, is it possible to generate the suffix of a sentence using custom analyzers? I would love to see that.

Comment: of course you can do it, I had a similar need at some point, you can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666371/how-to-wisely-combine-shingles-and-edgengram-to-provide-flexible-full-text-searc (it's not the exact solution you need, but look for the `ends_with` field) as it will show you how to set up such analyzers)