# How to access mapping sub-fields in painless?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Assuming there is an Elasticsearch mapping:

```
    "mappings": {
      "dynamic_templates": [],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "x": {
              "type": "completion"
            },
            "y": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "z": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "shingles",
              "fielddata": true
            }
        }
```

How can I access `name.x/y/z` data/tokens from painless script?

Below are not working:

```
ctx._source.name.x
ctx._source['name.fields.x']
ctx._source['name.x']
```

Comment: In what context is your painless script executing?

Comment: What do you mean? It's Elasticsearch.

Comment: I know, I mean the [Painless context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/8.6/painless-contexts.html). Aggregation script, query script, runtime field, etc?

Comment: Update by query

Comment: Ok and what do you want to do exactly? Assign a value or read the value of the field? Can you show what your script is doing?

Comment: Ideally take the shingles tokens from `z` sub-field and store it in in new field like `ctx.shingles` (as an array as there will be many tokens).

Comment: Update by query can only access the raw document through the `ctx._source` variable, and as such, it doesn't have access to the indexed tokens stored in the sub-fields.

Comment: That's very bad - does any other context allows that i.e. ingest? How I can access the tokens in the script then? I know there is a `termvectors` API but I can't use it in the script, right?

Comment: What's your use case? What do you want to do with those tokens ultimately?

Comment: I want to use shingles to populate suggestion's input data - I want this to happen during ingestion or by manually running update script.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see, you want some kind of retro-loop of whatever is produced in `name.z` to be fed into `name.x`. First, I think there's a misconception in the way you think multi-fields are working. You only ever get to specify the value for the `name` field and each of the sub-field will get a value according to whatever type/analyzer it has, but **you cannot** specify a value directly for any of those sub-fields.

What you should do instead is to specify the `shingles` analyzer in your completion field directly and that should do the trick.

**UPDATE**

What you want to do is not possible automatically and not with multi-fields, you need a standalone `completion` field, not as sub-field of `name`. The process you want can be done like this, but needs to be coded on client-side:

```
# 1. Index your document
PUT test/_doc/1
{ "name": "the big brown fox" }

# 2. For each indexed document, retrieve the term vectors for name.z
GET test/_termvectors/1?fields=name.z

=> 
  "term_vectors" : {
    "name.z" : {
      "field_statistics" : {
        "sum_doc_freq" : 7,
        "doc_count" : 1,
        "sum_ttf" : 7
      },
      "terms" : {
        "big" : {
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 1,
              "start_offset" : 4,
              "end_offset" : 7
            }
          ]
        },
        "big brown" : {
          "term_freq" : 1,
          "tokens" : [
            {
              "position" : 1,
              "start_offset" : 4,
              "end_offset" : 13
            }
          ]
        },

# 3. Retrieve all the keys from the terms map obtained in step 2
"big", "big brown", ...

# 4. Feed the retrieved tokens back into the document's top-level completion field
POST test/_doc/1/_update
{
   "doc": {
       "completion": {
           "input": [ "big", "big brown", ... ],
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly like that. Completion suggester requires indexing `input` values - I want to do this to be taken from field shingles automatically during ingestion or by running update query. Above proposal doesn't work as shingles are not returned as `options->text` suggestion results but full name value.

Comment: I can say it's very related to this one - with the exception that author is manually creating tokens - I want them to be taken from index (after shingle analyzer created them): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68225617/elasticsearch-how-to-provide-value-to-an-inner-field-in-ingest-pipeline

Comment: Still, there's a misconception, because you cannot set values directly on `name.x`. With multi-fields, you only set the value of `name` and all sub-fields will be indexed automatically depending on their type and analyzer.

Comment: I've added a sample process that would allow to achieve what you want

Comment: The initial problem of the question was how to read the multi-field value and reuse it for another field - it doesn't have to be `name.x` it can be another root field like `new_field` of type `completion` where `.input` can be set.

Comment: In the update by query context, you don't have access to the indexed tokens, only to the raw values present in the _source.

Comment: Thanks for the sample process - this is something I knew already but it's manual. Of course I can do some "external" script to run these APIs, collect tokens and update documents but I was hoping that can it be done in kind of script in Elasticsearch (doesn't have to be update context) - I'm just wondering if it's even doable. Thanks for the support!

Comment: Glad that you knew already, would have been worth mentioning what you already explored when explaining your case :-)

Comment: I've mentioned `termvectors` in yesterdays discussion and asked if this can be used in painless script - I was aware I can take tokens from there and assign it "externally".

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware of that discussion. Aside from that, I'm curious about the underlying use case, i.e. how you're querying this completion data. How useful is it to have "big" and "big brown" as input in a completion field?

Comment: No problem :) What I'm trying to understand if there is any option in Elasticsearch to read tokens and assign them it within internal script - doesn't have to be update context or even painless language(?).

Comment: Maybe I'm just stupid but I just want to return related 1-3 word token of the name for given input prefix - not whole name. Like you type "elastic" in google you will get: "elastic search", "elastic man", "elastic cloud".